# How to search answers created by specific users with a specific tags?

Tags: support, answers, search

Suppose I wanted to find all the answers which are tagged with `selenium` as an example that have been done by the user - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2462559/babai. How do you search for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the search box:

[`user:2462559 [selenium] is:a`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2462559%20%5Bselenium%5D%20is:a)

Or you can go to his [tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2462559/babai?tab=tags) and click on particular tag. However it will show you both questions and answers.

Comment: You guys are awesome! I got the one I was looking for. Here it is - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2462559+[selenium]+is%3Aa . It will help me to find the answer as per need quickly. BTW if any such need comes,is their any repository which I can look for by myself or I need to come here always.. :)

Comment: @user153138 - Regarding advanced search you can refer this help center page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: If I do need to search say by using ruby and selenium then ?

Comment: @user153138 - Then simply add another tag in the search box: [`user:2462559 [selenium] [ruby] is:a`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2462559+%5Bselenium%5D+%5Bruby%5D+is%3Aa). You can also search for multiple tags like this: [`user:2462559 [selenium] or [ruby] is:a`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2462559+%5Bselenium%5D+or+%5Bruby%5D+is%3Aa)